# How to tell if jetpack-compose pagination is working?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging

How can you tell if paging is working properly?  All the examples I've looked at involve using `retrofit apiservice` which appears to be returning pages of data, but I'm pulling down a single rss feed and parsing it into a giant `List<POJO>`.  I suspect that my `PagingSource` is loading the entire list into one page, but I'm not sure how to tell.

My list has near 1000 items, so I assume it'd be good practice to implement some kind of paging/DiffUtil.  I'm playing around in this with `jetpack compose` using`androidx.paging:paging-compose:1.0.0-alpha12` which probably complicates things.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

```
class RssListSource(): PagingSource<Int, RssItem>() {
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, RssItem> {
        return try {

            val nextPage = params.key ?: 1
            val rssList: List<RssItem> = RssFeedFetcher().fetchRss()

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = rssList,
                prevKey = if (nextPage == 1) null else nextPage - 1,
                nextKey = nextPage.plus(1)
            )
        } catch (e: Exception){
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivityViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val rss: Flow<PagingData<RssItem>> = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 10)){
        RssListSource()  // returned to LazyPagingItems list in @Composable 
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data still needs a way to fetch pages of data. I would expect your RssFeedFetcher to use the page information and return a page accordingly.

You are probably correct that you are currently returning all items at once.

Answer (score 0):

There's two main strategies here:

1. Add a long enough `delay()` to `load()` such that you have enough time to scroll to the end of the list before new page loads

```
class RssListSource(): PagingSource<Int, RssItem>() {
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, RssItem> {
  delay(5000)
  ...
}
```

2. Observe changes to `LazyPagingItems.loadState` and look for either PREPEND or APPEND switching between Loading and NotLoading.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to be able to implement pagination with the paging library you need to use a paginated API, that means that in your example, you'd need a way to fetch the RSS in a paginated fashion. The Paging library won't be able to make use of pagination if your data source does not provide a way to query for paginated data, unfortunately.

You could achieve what you want by implementing a middleware that fetches the RSS feed and splits it into pages for you to query from the Android app.

EDIT: Another approach could be to have a background task (using the Android WorkManager) to download the RSS feed and save it in a Room Database, then use the Paging library to load pages off the database. Here's a summary of how to show paginated data from a Room database: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db